# how to use VBS run Excel Macro, but not run the Workbook_Open()

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

Need your help. 
I want to use vbs file to run excel macro, in the xlsm file there is Workbook_Open(), I don't want to run it, I want to run some other macro, eg, Module1.test1111

But when I open open the excel file in vbs, or run other macro directly by using below code, the Workbook_Open() will run automatically.

Please give some advice how to avoid Workbook_Open() run, thanks.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Visible = true
objExcel.Application.Run "'test1.xlsm'!Module1.test1111"
```

Comment: Try adding `objExcel.Application.EnableEvents = False` before starting your macro

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak Just saw your comment. If you want to post it as an answer, I will delete mine. Was testing my code before posting and did not see your comment...

Comment: It's ok, leave your one :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout How about instead you both find a duplicate and flag it as such, it’s not the first time this exact problem has been answered.

Comment: @Lankymart: Feel free to close it as a duplicate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to specify the `Application`. `objExcel` is the `Application`. And to disable the `Workbook_Open()`, switch off the events

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = true
objExcel.EnableEvents = False
objExcel.Run "'C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sample.xlsm'!Module1.test1111"
```

Also remember to switch them back on ;)